# Optimization/scaling use case concerning a SQL RDMS join

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, server

I'm creating a platform that will allows users to save pages on an AWS S3 bucket. The page will have as much static information listed as is possible, but I still need the page to issue a query (AJAX) that will touch my server. This query can get all the information it needs from a single table with one exception, a full name. To do this, I need the query to join a second table.

I read about joins not being server intensive, and then find another article that says they are. If these queries are executed a lot, let's say hundreds of thousands of times, should I just include this full name in the original table so that I don't need the join? How much optimization would this yield based on the above metric?

MYSQL schema -

```
TABLE: pet
pet_key, int, pk
pet_type_key, int
pet_name, varchar
color, varchar
weight, decimal
user_key

TABLE: user
user_key
full_name
email_address
password
```

---

I could recreate the schema so I don't need a join -

```
TABLE: pet
pet_key, int, pk
pet_type_key, int
pet_name, varchar
color, varchar
weight, decimal
user_key
user_full_name, varchar // duplicate data, but faster to retrieve

TABLE: user
user_key
full_name
email_address
password
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Also show us the two alternative table designs.

Comment: What happened to the password and email address? Did you forget them, or didn't it feel right to store them in the pets table ;-)

Comment: Stick with the current design.

Comment: But is it inefficient to do the extra joins? Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: It may be inefficient to denormalize, since larger rows mean fewer rows per physical page. It depends on your query, indexes and storage engine. Go with a normalized design until it becomes inefficient to do so, then test the alternatives.

Comment: "Hundreds of thousands" per hour?  No problem with either solution.  Per minute - either solution may have a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comment suggests, you are overthinking this.

Relational databases are designed to combine data from multiple tables, and most databases support a wide variety of join algorithms to accomplish this.

In your case, you would want a query such as:

```
select *
from pets p join
     users u
     using (user_key);
```

You want to be sure that you have an index on `users(user_key)`.  Normally, this column would be declared as a primary key, which guarantees an index on the column.

Your proposed approach of duplicating data introduces other problems.  Perhaps a user can change his/her name over time.  The `pets` table would have inconsistent names.  Another issue is storage.  Why store more data than necessary?